# This HTML5 code is not playing audio and video

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

I am learning HTML5 and somehow I am not able to get this work.
Also I am new to Stack Overflow. Sorry for the mistakes made!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video and Audio</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>VIDEO</h1>
<video controls="true" autoplay="true" width="500"> 
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
    <source src="video.MOV" type="video/MOV"/>
    Your browser does not support the <code>video</code>element
</video>
<br>
    <h1>AUDIO</h1>
    <audio controls = "true">
    <source src = "Jeena Jeena.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src = "Jeena Jeena.MP3" type="audio/mpeg"/>JEENA JEENA SONG</audio>
    <br>
    <p>HOPE YOU ENJOYED THIS TUTORIAL!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid submitting questions that read "Please help" without any context. Interesting information would be the expected and actual behavior of your code. In your particular case: Are you serving this html file from a webserver or are you simply displaying a local file (file:// in your address bar) in your browser?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for guiding me. As I mentioned I am learning HTML5 hence, I just open it in my browser as a local file.